# rails link_to unable to direct to create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I've been reading a few posts on this but no matter how I try I cant seem to escape being routed to the wrong place.

My rails routes state

```
venue_bookings GET    /venues/:venue_id/bookings(.:format) bookings#index                          
              POST    /venues/:venue_id/bookings(.:format)  bookings#create
```

So by that this route should route to post

```
= link_to 'Make a booking', venue_bookings_path(venue, booking_params: {venue_id: venue.id, event_id: event.id, booked_from: event.start}), method: :post
```

Instead I am being sent to the index action for which there isn't one. I need to route it to the create action.

I should note that the link_to is within a form_for block, but I doubt that should matter right?

Comment: And you can confirm that you have included JavaScript and it is working/not disabled?

Comment: i think so, how can I be sure? I checked chrome debugger and .js files are being loaded

Comment: @RyanK there is a   =javascript_include_tag "application" at the top of my layouts file so i assume it must be

Comment: If you have a `javascript_include_tag` somewhere in your layout file you should be good. I'm not sure what is wrong. I'd try changing `:post` to `"POST"`. I'd also try eliminating the index route since it seems like you don't need it. Other than that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I had to ensure 'rails_ujs' was included in the application.js file. The ujs file allows a link to the create action.